# Does primitive value have member methods in strict mode?

Tags: javascript

Primitive value needs associated object wrapper to access methods, like `String` object is needed to access `String.prototype.charAt` for primitive `string`, but below code seems imply that `getTypeScript` is a member method on the primitive value itself. Is the method really attached to primitive value in **strict** mode, or there are other explanations?

```
Object.prototype.getTypeStrict = function() {
    "use strict";
    return typeof this;
};
console.log("".getTypeStrict()); // string
```

Comment: The value of `this` in strict mode will be whatever you directly set it to be. So instead of converting a primitive string to a `String`, it'll be the actual primitive string. This also means that it could be `null` or `undefined` instead of the default `window`.

Comment: ...where the method is "attached" however hasn't changed. It's still the same prototype chain traversal. Calling a method on a primitive has always been possible. That doesn't mean it was actually an object wrapper. It would just wrap the primitive in the method before, and now it doesn't.

Comment: as i understand it, primitive strings are "upgraded" when methods are invoked, but not in general.

Comment: @squint if strict mode doesn't do any object/value conversion when calling a method on it, then how could `getTypeStrict` be resolved? There is no inheritance relationship between primitive `string` and `Object.prototype`.  Without strict mode, there is wrapper `String` object created which is instance of `Object`.

Comment: Why would there need to be an object wrapper created to look up a method? If the type is a primitive string, then the runtime has enough information to look up methods on `String.prototype` and then `Object.prototype` without any sort of conversion or wrapping. The `this` value of a method isn't *necessarily* a reflection of an object/method relationship. This is evident in that you can manually set `this` to whatever value you want. `myFunc.call(undefined)` will set `this` to `undefined` in strict mode, which can't have methods, or to `window` in non-strict, which is clearly not `undefined`.

Comment: ...In JS, `this` is really more like an immutable function parameter that always gets defined *(except in arrow functions)*. Often it does indeed get defined as the value (perhaps wrapped) on which the method was called, but that's certainly not always the case.

Comment: @squint if "the type is a primitive string, then the runtime has enough information to look up methods on `String.prototype`" is true, then what's the necessitate to create Object wrapper for primitive value?

Comment: @Thomson: I honestly don't know what the reasoning originally was to do that. Either way, the type information must be there. After all, if there's enough info to know to convert it to a `String` wrapper, then there's enough info to perform lookups on `String.prototype`. All that's left then is to set the value of `this`, which acts really more like a function parameter than some absolute, object/method relationship. The addition of "strict mode" sought to fix perceived flaws in the language, so they did apparently see altering/converting `this` as a flaw.